# How to fill a 2D Array with stings from a text file/

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have to build a matrix/grid with the following text file.

```
.0...00...
.0F0......
..0..0....
.0.0.....0
..........
..........
....0.0.0.
.0.0......
0........0
S.0.....00
```

I'm using a 2D array but having problems filling the array with the above strings.
What can I do to populate the 2D array with those strings?

```
public static void readFile() throws IOException {
String txtFile = "path to txt file";

        int rows = 0;
        int cols = 0;
    
        //get no. of rows
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(txtFile));
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            s.nextLine();
            rows++;
        }
    
        //get no. of columns
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFile));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String getCol;
        while((getCol = r.readLine()) != null){
            list.add(getCol);
        }
        cols = list.size();
    
       //initialize array
        String[][] grid = new String[rows][cols];
        for(int i =0; i < grid.length; i++){
            for(int j =0; j < grid.length; j++){
                    if(s.hasNext()){
                        grid[i][j] = s.next();
                    }
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: `I'm using a 2D array but having problems filling the array ...` What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all that kerfuffle. Your using Scanner to get the number of rows in the file, so why not use it to get everything else? Just close the file once you have the number of lines then reopen it again:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(txtFile));
int rows = 0;
while (s.hasNextLine()){
    s.nextLine();
    rows++;
}
s.close();
```

Because it's a Square Matrix (same number of rows as there are columns in each row) you can now declare and initialize the matrix (2D) array:

```
String[][] matrix = new String[rows][rows];
```

Now just use the same Scanner object to reopen the file and actually fill the matrix with data. **Keep in mind**....a 2D Array in Java is an Array of Arrays.

```
s = new Scanner(new File(txtFile));
int rowCounter = 0;
while (s.hasNextLine()){
    matrix[rowCounter] = s.nextLine().trim().split("");
    rowCounter++;
}
s.close();
```

Notice how the matrix (2D Array) is filled. Because a 2D array is an Array of Arrays you just need to what array the row is to hold. The code:

```
s.nextLine().trim().split("");
```

splits the read in line into a String[] array which is what you need. So the line:

```
matrix[rowCounter] = s.nextLine().trim().split("");
```

is basically the same as:

```
String[] lineArray = s.nextLine().trim().split("");
matrix[rowCounter] = lineArray;
```

The `matrix` 2D Array at the row specified by the integer variable `rowCounter` (which starts from 0) now holds a String[] Array of the current line read. Now the `rowCounter` variable is incremented by 1: `rowCounter++;` in preparation for the next file line to be processed and added to the 2D Array.

The whole thing might look like:

```
try {
    //get no. of rows/columns
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(txtFile));
    int rows = 0;
    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        s.nextLine();
        rows++;
    }
    s.close();
        
    String[][] matrix = new String[rows][rows];
        
    s = new Scanner(new File(txtFile));
    int rowCounter = 0;
    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        matrix[rowCounter] = s.nextLine().trim().split("");
        rowCounter++;
    }
    s.close();
        
    // Print the Matrix (2D Array)...
    for (String[] strg : matrix) {
        for (String str : strg) {
            System.out.print(str);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the Console Window should display:

```
.0...00...
.0F0......
..0..0....
.0.0.....0
..........
..........
....0.0.0.
.0.0......
0........0
S.0.....00
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! I realized my code was far too cluttered making it really difficult to wrap my head around.
Thank you very much!